# Create folder if path does not exist?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf-generation

I am using the code below to save a pdf file to a network location. Is it possible that if the path does not exist that it creates the folder? The code below is just adding the username to the file name when I need it to create the username's folder?

```
    Dim Doc1 As New Document
    Dim path As String = "\\Servername\PDFs\" + Session("Username")


    Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", random)
    Dim combinedData As String = path & myUniqueFileName
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create))
    Doc1.Open()
    Dim test As String
    test = Session("PDF")
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))

    Doc1.Close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, like this:

```
If(Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) Then
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
End If
```

Comment: Looks like that created the folder but the pdf didnt get save to the new directory? It saved it to the root?

Comment: Do you include a "\" in `Session("Username")?` I'm going to assume that you don't. If that is the case, you may want to change this line:

`Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", random)`

to

`Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("\{0}.pdf", random)`

Comment: Also, `System.IO.Path.Combine` will take care of the slashes for you (so you don't end up with 0 or 2 slashes, etc.).  Example: `Path.Combine(path, myUniqueFileName)`